# Triple Combobox button Assistance needed

Tags: combobox

I have this triple combo script and when the third option is selected, it automatically redirects you. What I need is for this to stop and be executed instead by a button. Would really appreciate it if anyone can help. I have tried to fix it but I'm a newbie. Not sure how to post the code so here if a link. Thanks

http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=275240

Comment: Can you post your code as you have it now?

Comment: Mine is basically the same thing just slightly different. But I'm using the default to figure out how to get a button working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the code on the link provided, the 3rd option has an "onchange" attribute that will call the "redirect2" function.

Although looking at the function itself, I am not so sure whether the function is capable of doing redirection. However, if you want to disable the redirection, you can remove the "onchange" attribute.

If you really need the function to keep being used (e.g. for updating any states/values), then you need to add return false at the end of the "onchange" attribute, for example:

```
onChange="redirect2(this.options.selectedIndex); return false;"
```

Cheers  :))

> > > > >
> > > >         (The above solution did not work)
> > > >         >
> > > >         Edited to:

```
var nextPage = "";
function redirect2(z){
//parent.chartsloader.location=temp1[z].value
//parent.location=temp1[z].value
nextPage = temp1[z].value;
}

function goToNextPage()
{
    if(document.isc.example.options.selectedIndex > 0 && document.isc.stage2.selectedIndex > 0 && document.isc.stage3.selectedIndex > 0)
        window.location = nextPage;
}
```

Comment: Well that didn't seem to work. Once a option from the third category is select it still auto redirects me. I may have to find another triple combobox. Thank you though.

Comment: Sorry for that, I finally found that parent.location is the thing that cause the redirection, so I put the alternative for your previous code on to my previous comment above.

( I can't format the code properly here in the comment section, so please see above )

Cheers...  :))

Comment: Well I have tried to cut and paste, which didn't work. So I'm either not doing something right, I using a wrong type of go/submit button, or the code doesn't work. I am most likely doing something wrong. I really appreciate the help though, thanks.

Comment: oooh... that's unfortunate. I tried it and it worked on IE, Firefox and Chrome. If you still want to try, I uploaded the complete working source on:
<br/>
<a href="swinphp.herokuapp.com">swinphp.herokuapp.com</a>
<br/>
You can open the web page and view the source.

Comment: Dang it was the button I was using. Thank you Very Very Much! Btw you got facebook or something? Tried to pm you but there is no pm option.